# linq-to-sql SingleOrDefault return when null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a linq-to-sql query and I'm loading an ID (a `bigint` in the database and a `long` in my code) from a table, something like this:

```
var SomeQuery = (from x in ...
                 select x.ID).SingleOrDefault();
```

When I get the result, I use `SingleOrDefault` in case the return is empty. Does that mean that if the result is empty the `SomeQuery` variable will be 0 or null?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it? That would be a simple way to find out...

Comment: @MarcGravell: my current sample data has data in the DB table and it's not yet tested for the cases where there's no data (ie. user just signed-up).

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you think it's a dumb question then know that I think that asking dumb questions is a smart way to learn.

Comment: @frenchie: I think it is poorly worded, I had to read it 3 times to grasp the issue. +1 anyways

Comment: @leppie: ok, thanks; I always strive to make my questions as clear as possible but I know it's not always the case.

Comment: if the column has no value the result (NULL), unless you have a default value in the table that invoke

Comment: This question could be rephrased to: Why is this result in some cases `Null` and in other cases `0`?

Comment: Did you ever manahed to assign null to a int? The default value of int is 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look the [documenation for SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx)

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more
>   than one element in the sequence.

It cleary states that if the sequence is empty it will return the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) which for long and bigint is **0**.  **Why explained below**

Documenation for [default keyword states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)

> In generic classes and methods, one issue that arises is how to assign
>   a default value to a parameterized type T when you do not know the
>   following in advance:
>
> Whether T will be a reference type or a value type.
>
> If T is a value type, whether it will be a numeric value or a struct.
>
> Given a variable t of a parameterized type T, the statement t = null
>   is only valid if T is a reference type and t = 0 will only work for
>   numeric value types but not for structs. The solution is to use the
>   default keyword, which will return null for reference types and **zero**
>   for numeric value types.

Comment: yes, I can read the doc. Does "or a default value if the sequence is empty" mean null or 0 in my case?

Comment: Did you ever manahed to assign null to a int? The default value of int is 0

Answer (score 0):

Default is returned if no element found.(default value of int is 0)

Value is returned if one is found.

Exception is thrown if more than one is found.