# LINQ new instance when SingleOrDefault returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this simple method:

```
    #region Fields

    private Collection<Address> _addresses;

    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    public Address DeliveryAddress()
    {
        if (_addresses == null)
            if (this.Id > 0)
                _addresses = Core.Data.Addresses.GetClient(this.Id);

        return _addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery);
    }

    public Address InvoiceAddress()
    {
        if (_addresses == null)
            if (this.Id > 0)
                _addresses = Core.Data.Addresses.GetClient(this.Id);

        return _addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Invoice);
    }

    #endregion
```

As you can see I trying to return one result for a `DeliveryAddress` and one result for an `InvoiceAddress`. My problem is that I would like the link expression to create a new instance of `Address()` if `SingleOrDefault` returns `null`.
I am really new to linq, so I am not sure whether `SingleOrDefault` is the correct expression I should be using.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594355/linq-to-sql-singleordefault-return-when-null

Comment: You might want to look into the `.Any()` function.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) and use that instance as default value:

```
return _addresses.Where(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery)
                 .DefaultIfEmpty(new Adress())
                 .Single();
```

Comment: In this case you can also use `Single` instead of `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: @w0lf Yes, that would be less confusing.

Answer (score 14):

Use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
return _addresses
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery) ?? new Address();
```

---

The expression

```
x ?? y
```

yields `x` if `x` is not `null`, otherwise `y`. You can chain the operator

```
x ?? y ?? z ?? t
```

This returns the first non-null value or `null` if all of them are `null`.

---

**UPDATE**

Note that [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) throws an exception if the sequence has more than one element. If you need the first element of a sequence possibly having no or more than one element, use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own extension method, like this:

```
public static T NewIfNull<T>(this T obj) where T: class, new()
{
   return obj ?? new T();
}
```

... then tack a usage onto the end of SingleOrDefault:

```
var singleResult = myCollection.SingleOrDefault().NewIfNull();
```

... or because the logic is so simple, just inline it as other answers have said.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return _addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery);
```

Do something like this:

```
var address = _addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery);

if(address == null)
    address = new Address();

return address;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to write both of these as extension methods on `IEnumerable<Address>`. You can use the null-coalesing operator to return a new instance if the `SingleOrDefault()` call returns `null`.

```
public static class AddressExtensions
{
    public static Address DeliveryAddress(this IEnumerable<Address> addresses)
    {
        return addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery) 
               ?? new Address();
    }

    public static Address InvoiceAddress(this IEnumerable<Address> addresses)
    {
        return addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Invoice) 
               ?? new Address();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from alternatives in other answers,  you can also create your own `SingleOrNew` Extension method.

```
public static TSource SingleOrNew<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate ) where T:new()
{
     return source.SingleOrDefault(predicate) ?? new T();
}
```

It can be used as

```
return _addresses.SingleOrNew(x => x.TypeId == AddressType.Delivery);
```