# Why dapper QuerySingleOrDefault returns null?

Tags: c#, dapper

I have this piece of code

```
return await dbConn.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<CacheItem>(sqlQuery, new { clientId, key });
```

Correct me if I am wrong, if I call QueryFirstOrDefault or QuerySingleOrDefault and there are no records found (or table is empty) then I should get an empty CacheItem, right?

Instead I get null, am I missing something?

P.S. If I add records to the table, then I get a CacheItem object, filled with the values from db.

Comment: Running a `*OrDefault` method will return null if the return type is a reference type (class), not an "empty" instance of that type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ new instance when SingleOrDefault returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093594/linq-new-instance-when-singleordefault-returns-null)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "an empty CacheItem"?

Comment: @gunr2171 I think he means an instance of `CacheItem` with default properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CacheItem` is a `class` it will return `null`. If it is a `struct` it will return a default instance of `CacheItem`

Comment: `CacheItem` _must_ be a class; the result is `null`.